# What X keysym to use for rfkill / flight mode?

Tags: xorg, shortcut-keys

On my laptop Fn+F12 toggles flight mode in windows. I'd like the same functionality in Linux and am looking for the appropriate X keysym that will invoke the equivalent of `rfkill block all` when mapped with xmodmap.

I can see there is XF86WLAN and XF86Bluetooth, but they are not what I'm after. I want it to kill/enable all radio devices.

I'm not after the script that would do this (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17734/is-it-possible-to-setup-a-shortcut-for-enable-disable-wifi) for example), but wondering if Ubuntu has this functionality already hooked up and if so, what keysym to set up in xmodmap.

Answer (score 1):

I found the easiest way to set keys is to use "key touch"

Open a terminal and enter these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install keytouch keytouch-editor
```

You should now be able to find KeyTouch under System > Administration.

- KeyTouch-Editor - The tool to setup your keyboard by teaching it. You select your multimedia keyboards input, then press keys and identify them from a drop down list. Save the configuration file when your done and simply import into Keytouch itself.

[read more](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KeyTouch)
[image]
[source](http://keytouch.sourceforge.net/index.php)