# Stop airplane mode from starting bluetooth

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, bluetooth, dell

Using Ubuntu 19.04 on a dell XPS 13 9380.

When turning off airplane mode, the bluetooth is turned on, whatever the state it was in before turning airplane mode on.

Is there any way to control what airplane mode is doing when it is turned on?

Or better still, is there a way to remap the hot key (on my laptop it is the little tower one used with Fn), to only toggle on/off the wifi? This would avoid tweaking the airplane mode actions.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a GNOME extension as workaround for this. It is called "Sane Airplane Mode". Have a look at it at [GitHub](https://github.com/AntiKippi/gnome-shell-extension-sane-airplane-mode) or [GNOME Extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4604/sane-airplane-mode/).

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. Running 18.04.3 (Gnome) on a Thinkpad X230

Steps to reproduce:

1. In Apps->Settings turn on Wifi, turn off bluetooth
2. Hit Fn+F5 -> Airplane Mode gets enabled, both Wifi & BT are off
3. Hit Fn+F5 again, both Wifi and bluetooth are switched on

Expected behaviour would be Wifi on, bluetooth off as it was.

Seems to be a known issue with Gnome:

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=787800

Remapping the hotkey to toggle only Wifi instead of Airplane Mode would sound like an option, but it seems Airplane Mode is being activated automatically whenever both Wifi and BT are switched off..

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/issues/131

Which is a little bit of a bummer for people who rarely use bluetooth and rarely travel by plane :)

Comment: For now, the workaround I use is a shortcut to directly toggle wifi on and off: https://askubuntu.com/a/17744/983220.