# How do I turn on WiFi without mouse/trackpad?

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, navigation

After turning on my laptop, I found my trackpad not working. I don't have separate mouse on me.

To troubleshoot, I'd need to surf the Internet, but of well I have disabled wifi on computer before turning it off

If I had mouse working, enabling wifi would've been 3 clicks `corner->wifi->turn on` (automatic log in is enabled), but, due to keyboard navigation in gnome being awful, I don't understand how to repeat those actions in my situation...

Right now I have phone to ask question here, but using it isn't comfortable (and i need to put it charging and not temper with it)

So... Please help?

---

Also, is there any program that allows to control cursor with keyboard? Would be of great help too

Comment: super+v or super+m then right arrow then up or down and choose WiFi enter.. or similar..

Comment: or you can make it with terminal command also `nmcli radio wifi on`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to open your terminal. Now use `nmcli` command to turn your wifi radio on:

```
nmcli r wifi on
```

where `r` option stands for **r**adio.

If the wifi doesn't connect automatically, follow the steps below.

List the available WiFi networks:

```
nmcli d wifi list
```

where `d` option stands for **d**evices.

Now connect to your access point (for example) 'my_wifi':

```
nmcli d wifi connect my_wifi password <password>
```

where `<password>` is the password for the connection.

**P.S.**

To troubleshoot your trackpad problem, use this [wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a shortcut but you can do it in the terminal. To disable your wifi adapter use the command `rfkill block wifi`. To enable it use `rfkill unblock wifi`. You can also create your [shortcuts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17734/is-it-possible-to-setup-a-shortcut-for-enable-disable-wifi).